Have we lost the ability of created project with separate authentication with the new abp.studio.cli?
Been playing with the new abp studio and the beta volo.abp.studio.cli. It seems that we now require a team license to create projects with separate authentication server. If I try to create Blazor Webapp project, I use --tiered or --separate-authserver.
Am I missing something? If not are we loosing existing functionality on the new abp studio platform?
I was expecting to be able to create a project with separate authentication server using community abp cli

Do you need ABP to do this for you?

@Dai I can certainly create all the projects manually and wire them up. This has been feature from a long time and I would like to understand if it was removed and now is a paid feature only.
